# You have already activated rake 10.1 .1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your comm and may solve this.

Tags: exec, bundle

"You have already activated rake 10.1
.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.4.2. Prepending `bundle exec` to your comm
and may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)"
I am facing this issue. I tried with other existing answers in stachoverflow.
But still the issue cann't resolve.
Can anybody suggest..please..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12):

gem list | grep rake

if you see two versions of rake, then

```
gem uninstall rake -v 10.4.2
```

Comment: that worked! .. two different version were causing problems! thanks

Comment: reinstall work for me `gem uninstall rake` and `gem install rake`

Answer (score 2):

You need to update your Gemfile.lock. Do this:

`bundle update rake`

Answer (score 1):

Run 'bundle update' to fix the version issues.
This fixed for me, and I was getting the exact error as you.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the version mentioned in gem file. It works